# how to specify depended library source file path in CMake

Tags: cmake

We can use `target_link_libraries` to specify libraries when linking a given target.

I am wondering if there is a way to specify libraries source file path (cpp file)? (not the header file which can be set using `target_include_directories`)

Because some debug tools(`cgdb`, `gdbgui`) can't find the source file of depended library. (All the targets and libraries are compiled with debugging option.)

Currently, I have to add the source file of library to the main target when debugging.

myproj  CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9 FATAL_ERROR)                                                                                                                          
set(PORJ_NAME myproj)
project(${PORJ_NAME})

add_executable(${PORJ_NAME}
        main.cpp 
        ...
)
target_link_libraries (${PORJ_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        /proj_math/libmathcore.so
        ...
)
```

mathcore CMakeLists.txt (located in different path from myproj)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9 FATAL_ERROR)                                                                                                                          
set(PORJ_NAME mathcore)
project(${PORJ_NAME})

add_library(${PORJ_NAME}
         src/mathcore.cpp  # change to absolute path won't work either
        ...
)
```

Comment: "some debug tools can't find the source file of depended library." - Please, elaborate that (which tool, CMake generator, example,  etc.). As far as I know, CMake doesn't have a target's property to store directories with the source files. Debug tools normally refers to the source files using their absolute paths.

Comment: Hi Tsyvarev, I have updated the post.

Comment: `can't find the source file of depended library` do you compile the library with debugging options? Is the source file in debugging information inside the library stored as full path or relative? Is the debugger running relative to the sources of the library? `cgdb, gdbgui` - these both is one debug tool `gdb`, not two. You specify library sources inside `add_library` cmake command.

Comment: Hi Kamil Cuk, All the libraries are compiled with debug option. Thanks for pointing out "the path is full path or relative". I will check it .

Comment: @KamilCuk It seems the issue doesn't cause by relative path. I change it to absolute path in mathcore CMakeLists.txt , it doesn't help.